# Efecto del scope de las variables en el tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c++

En este portal me he encontrado con personas que opinan que el scope de las variables debe ser el mínimo imprescindible mientras que otras piensan que lo mejor es ampliar la vida de las mismas al máximo posible.

¿Qué ventajas aporta cada una de estas dos opciones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Norma general**

Lo recomendable, como norma general, es reducir al máximo el ámbito de las variables. Esta afirmación se sustenta en el hecho de que compartir una variable para diferentes usos suele complicar la lectura y mantenimiento del código.

- El compilador no nos avisará si se nos olvida inicializarla entre el primer uso y el segundo por muy restrictiva que sea la compilación.
- Será complicado paralelizar el algoritmo.
- El nombre de la variable será, generalmente, menos descriptivo, lo que complica la lectura del código.

Si encima declaramos las variables como globales el asunto se complica todavía más y ya ni que contar si aparte de variables globales empezamos a usar hilos.

**Scope vs rendimiento (tipos nativos)**

Un detalle que se suele alegar en defensa de alargar la vida de las variables es el tema del rendimiento. Se defiende que declarar la variable una sola vez evita que la misma se tenga que estar creando y destruyendo, por lo que mejora el rendimiento de la aplicación.

Esto no es técnicamente correcto, al menos no con compiladores modernos. Para demostrarlo vamos a usar un ejemplo como el siguiente:

```
extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc();

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();
  int i;

  for( i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    ExternFunc();
  }

  for( i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    ExternFunc();
  }
}
```

Las funciones están marcadas como `extern` porque no me interesa ni su contenido ni que el compilador las convierta en `inline`. Lo hago así para que los ejemplos sean más simples.

Si compilamos este código en modo release y analizamos el ensamblador resultante (para ello se puede usar esta [herramienta](https://godbolt.org/)) obtenemos una secuencia como la que sigue (ejemplo con gcc 6.2 compilado con -O3):

```
func1():
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 8
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    mov     ebp, eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L6:
    add     ebx, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebp, ebx
    jne     .L6
    xor     ebp, ebp
.L5:
    add     ebp, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebx, ebp
    jne     .L5
.L1:
    add     rsp, 8
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

El código básicamente está estructurado de la siguiente forma:

- .L6: Representa el inicio del primer bucle
- .L5: Representa el inicio del segundo bucle
- .L1: Una optimización a cuenta del compilador, si `num` vale 0 se salta directamente al final de la función.

Como se puede apreciar, el compilador está haciendo uso de los registros `ebx` para el primer bucle y `ebp` para segundo. En vez de crear la variable en la pila está haciendo uso de los registros internos del procesador. El coste de crear la variable es, en este caso, 0.

Ahora vamos con una segunda versión. En este caso el ámbito de la variable va a quedar reducido al ámbito del propio bucle:

```
extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc();

int func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    ExternFunc();
  }

  for( int j=0; j<num; j++ )
  {
    ExternFunc();
  }
}
```

El ensamblador resultante es el siguiente:

```
func1():
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 8
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    mov     ebp, eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L6: 
    add     ebx, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebp, ebx
    jne     .L6
    xor     ebp, ebp
.L5:
    add     ebp, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebx, ebp
    jne     .L5
.L1:
    add     rsp, 8
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Si se comparan ambas secuencias vemos que son exactamente iguales. Se usan exactamente los mismos registros `ebx` y `ebp` para cada bucle, luego crear las variables es un proceso *gratuíto*.

¿Qué sucede entonces si tenemos bucles anidados?

Ante el siguiente código:

```
extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc();

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<num; j++ )
      ExternFunc();
  }
}
```

El ensamblador resultante es el siguiente:

```
func1():
    push    r12
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    mov     ebp, eax
    xor     r12d, r12d
.L7:
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L3:
    add     ebx, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebp, ebx
    jne     .L3
    add     r12d, 1
    cmp     ebp, r12d
    jne     .L7
.L1:
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    ret
```

Vemos que nuevamente se vuelve a hacer uso de los registros del procesador. En este caso está usando `ebx` y `r12d`, pero siguen siendo registros del procesador, luego el coste de crear la variable `j` en cada iteración del primer bucle es 0.

Queda claro entonces que al usar tipos nativos no hay diferencia alguna entre compartir variables o no, luego los supuestos beneficios de ampliar el ámbito de las variables es, en este caso, un falso mito.

**Scope vs rendimiento (estructuras y clases)**

Para este ejemplo vamos a crear un wrapper que encapsula un entero e implementa las funciones mínimas necesarias para que el código compile:

```
struct IntWrapper
{
  int num;

  IntWrapper(int valor)
    : num(valor)
  { }

  IntWrapper& operator++(int)
  {
    num++;
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator<(IntWrapper const& otro)
  {
    return num < otro.num;
  }
};

extern IntWrapper PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc();

void func1()
{
  IntWrapper num = PideNumero();

  for( IntWrapper i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    for( IntWrapper j=0; j<num; j++ )
      ExternFunc();
  }
}
```

¿Qué sucede en este caso? Veamos:

```
func1():
    push    r12
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    mov     ebp, eax
    xor     r12d, r12d
.L6:
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L3:
    add     ebx, 1
    call    ExternFunc()
    cmp     ebp, ebx
    jne     .L3
    add     r12d, 1
    cmp     r12d, ebp
    jne     .L6
.L1:
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    ret
```

Sorprendentemente el código es prácticamente el mismo. El compilador es capaz de extraer el entero del wrapper y generar un código igual de eficiente que en los casos anteriores.

Ya solo nos falta comprobar qué sucede con el caso de clases más complejas. Un ejemplo usando `std::string` fuera del bucle:

```
#include <string>

extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc(std::string const&);

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  std::string cad = "ABCD";

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    ExternFunc(cad);
  }
}
```

Y su salida:

```
func1():
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 40
    call    PideNumero()
    mov     ebp, eax
    lea     rax, [rsp+16]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+16], 1145258561
    test    ebp, ebp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 4
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+20], 0
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
    jle     .L1
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L9:
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    ExternFunc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     ebp, ebx
    jne     .L9
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rax, [rsp+16]
    cmp     rdi, rax
    je      .L1
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L1:
    add     rsp, 40
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    ret
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
    mov     rbx, rax
    cmp     rdi, rdx
    je      .L7
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L7:
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Ahora el código es un poco más complejo de leer porque se está invocando código perteneciente al constructor y al destructor de la clase `string`.

Si ahora movemos la creación del `string` al interior del bucle:

```
#include <string>

extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc(std::string const&);

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    std::string cad = "ABCD";
    ExternFunc(cad);
  }
}
```

Nos queda lo siguiente:

```
func1():
    push    r12
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 32
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    lea     rbx, [rsp+16]
    mov     r12d, eax
    xor     ebp, ebp
.L9:
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], 1145258561
    mov     rdi, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbx
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 4
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+20], 0
    call    ExternFunc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    cmp     rdi, rbx
    je      .L3
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L3:
    add     ebp, 1
    cmp     r12d, ebp
    jne     .L9
.L1:
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    ret
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
    mov     rbx, rax
    cmp     rdi, rdx
    je      .L7
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L7:
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

El cambio más perceptible es que se han movido las instrucciones de construcción:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], 1145258561
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbx
mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 4
mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+20], 0
```

y destrucción del string:

```
call    operator delete(void*)
```

Al interior del bucle.

En este caso sí que se podría llegar a apreciar una disminución del rendimiento en el caso de declarar las variables dentro del bucle... pero espera... estamos hablando de una cadena con un valor fijo. ¿Qué sucedería si el valor de la cadena se modifica en cada iteración?

Veamos primero qué sucede si declaramos la variable fuera del bucle:

```
#include <string>

extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc(std::string const&);

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  std::string cad;

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    cad = std::string('A',i);
    ExternFunc(cad);
  }
}
```

Lo que resulta en:

```
func1():
    push    r13
    push    r12
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 72
    lea     r13, [rsp+16]
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    mov     r12d, eax
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], r13
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 0
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+16], 0
    jle     .L1
    lea     rax, [rsp+32]
    xor     ebx, ebx
    lea     rbp, [rax+16]
    jmp     .L16
.L5:
    movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+40]
    test    rax, rax
    mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rdx
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
    je      .L6
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rax
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+48], rcx
.L7:
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+40], 0
    mov     BYTE PTR [rax], 0
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    cmp     rdi, rbp
    je      .L8
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L8:
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    ExternFunc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     r12d, ebx
    je      .L21
.L16:
    lea     rdi, [rsp+32]
    movsx   edx, bl
    mov     esi, 65
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rbp
    call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    cmp     rdx, rbp
    je      .L4
    cmp     rax, r13
    jne     .L5
    movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+40]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rdx
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
.L6:
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rbp
    mov     rax, rbp
    jmp     .L7
.L4:
    lea     rsi, [rsp+32]
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    jmp     .L7
.L21:
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rax, [rsp+16]
    cmp     rdi, rax
    je      .L1
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L1:
    add     rsp, 72
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    pop     r13
    ret
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
    mov     rbx, rax
    cmp     rdi, rdx
    je      .L12
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L12:
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Y ahora vamos a dejar la cadena dentro del bucle:

```
#include <string>

extern int PideNumero();
extern void ExternFunc(std::string const&);

void func1()
{
  int num = PideNumero();

  for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
  {
    std::string cad = std::string('A',i);
    ExternFunc(cad);
  }
}
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
func1():
    push    r12
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 32
    call    PideNumero()
    test    eax, eax
    jle     .L1
    lea     rbp, [rsp+16]
    mov     r12d, eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L9:
    mov     rdi, rsp
    movsx   edx, bl
    mov     esi, 65
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rbp
    call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    ExternFunc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    cmp     rdi, rbp
    je      .L3
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L3:
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     r12d, ebx
    jne     .L9
.L1:
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbx
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    ret
    mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
    mov     rbx, rax
    cmp     rdi, rdx
    je      .L7
    call    operator delete(void*)
.L7:
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Para empezar vemos que si dejamos el `string` fuera del bucle el compilador realiza tres llamadas al destructor (al final de `.L13`, `.L4` y `.L9`) mientras que si declaramos la cadena dentro del bucle únicamente se llama al destructor en dos ocasiones (final de `.L9` y `.L1`). Además vemos que, en el caso de declarar la variable fuera del bucle, se realizan dos llamadas al constructor:

- Llamada al constructor por defecto

  ```
  mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 0
  test    r12d, r12d
  mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+16], 0
  ```
- Y al constructor copia:

  ```
  call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct(unsigned long, char)
  ```

Luego podemos ver que el supuesto beneficio de alargar la vida de las clases realmente no tiene por qué ser tan beneficioso. En el ejemplo propuesto declarar la clase fuera del bucle origina un código más largo y más lento que si intentamos reducir el ámbito de las variables al mínimo.

**Conclusión**

Se podrían presentar ejemplos en los que sacar las variables fuera del bucle daría como resultado un código más rápido. Aquí únicamente pretendía demostrar que afirmar categóricamente que eso de ampliar el scope de las variables es beneficioso es un mito. Unas veces será beneficioso y otras no.

Entonces, ¿cuándo hay que optar por una solución u otra? Mi recomendación es, en este caso, intentar reducir por costumbre el ámbito al mínimo. La necesidad de ampliar la vida de las variables es algo que debería surgir de forma natural si el algoritmo no cumple con los requisitos de velocidad (requisitos que pocas veces existen) y únicamente cuando un profiler te diga que el cambio es beneficioso para tus intereses.

Lo anterior lo comento porque es ciencia cierta que cualquier programador tiene unas aptitudes para encontrar cuellos de botella propias de un hámster, sobretodo en lenguajes orientados a objetos y con código de cierta complejidad. Soy consciente de que a todos nos pasa que en un momento dado desechamos una idea porque automáticamente intentamos medir mentalmente su rendimiento y deducimos que será demasiado pobre... dejemos que sea un análisis real el que nos confirme nuestras sospechas en vez de desechar buenas ideas basándonos en teorías efímeras afectadas por nuestro humor y nuestro cansancio.

**Nota final:** Si este hilo tiene buena aceptación consideraré marcar la respuesta como wiki de comunidad. Aun así me gustaría que más gente aportarse su punto de vista.

Comment: Excelente explicación!! Además gran aporte de godbolt.org